# Repeated IBM Mq reconnection message after receiving a message in queue

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, ibm-mq

I have a Springboot app running that consumes from a queue and publishes messages to a topic. The app starts up fine and is able to receive and publish messages successfully. However, after receiving the first message after starting up, the log files will get spammed with these few messages in a loop at around 30 seconds - 2 minute intervals:

```
"[JMSCThreadPoolWorker~5] com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteReconnectThread"
"Starting reconnection of child hconn 'com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession[:27183d05][connectionId=4D513451513023127202020202015Fa96205BD168,tradeIdentifier=22,remoteTraceIdentifier=1] to queue manager 'null'"
"JMSCThreadPoolWorker~5] com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteParentHconn"
"---------------------------------------------------------------------------"
"EXPLANATION: null"
"ACTION: null"
"Completed reconnection of parent hconn com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession[:27183d05][connectionId=4D513451513023127202020202015Fa96205BD168,tradeIdentifier=22,remoteTraceIdentifier=1]"
```

This does not seem to cause a problem with how the app is functioning as messages can still be received/publish but I want to understand what is the cause of this

Comment: Yes it is enabled

Comment: Do you have MQ JMS trace enabled?